# Linux | Где мой жёсткий диск?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Я перешёл с `Windows 10` на `Linux Mint Mate`. Я всё, сделал, установил. И у меня спросило, куда установить этот `Linux`. У меня жёсткий диск на 55 гигов, и там было только 60, и также, у меня 2 терабайта два диска. Я выбрал 60, т.к. это жесткий диск. Готово, у меня `Linux Mint Mate`. Только вот вопрос, где находятся системные файлы? Где находится так называемый диск `C:/`? Я новичок в `Linux`. Но я не тупенький, и зашёл в `Компьютер` на рабочем столе. Там у меня 5 дисков, хотя должно быть только 4 (1 жесткий и два терабайтных и один пол-терабайтный). И так, где хранятся мой жёсткий диск?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста!
Мой жёсткий диск от `Kingston`. Также, при просмотре места, пишет `Неизвестно`.

Comment: т.н. диск С находится там,  что именуется "Файловая система"

Comment: Спасибо, но что тогда за `KINGSTON SKC300S37A60G`?

Comment: @694201970 можете сказать?

Comment: Довольно древний SSD на 60 гигов

Comment: [классический вопрос, да](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/где_диск_c)